# Is work energy theorem $W=\Delta K$ or $W=\Delta E$?

Tags: energy, work

I know that work is the change in kinetic energy. I saw on an equation sheet that work is equal to the change in total energy. Is this true? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

The usual formulation of the work-energy theorem (writing $K$ for kinetic energy) is
$$ W_{net} = \Delta K \,. $$
Here the net work is interpreted as being the sum of that done by *all* forces acting on the object.

However, after you factor all the conservative forces into potential and move them to the energy side, you get (writing $E$ for the total energy)
$$ W_{nc} = \Delta E \,,$$
where $W_{nc}$ is the work done by all non-conservative forces.

I don't recall ever seeing this second version labeled as the work-energy relationship. Rather it is a special case of the conservation of energy.

The critical difference, is that the first form involves work done by *all* the forces acting on the object and the second form involves only the work done by those forces that have not been handled by writing a potential term for them.